# Security question to Youtube Data API Auth Token

Tags: security, authentication, oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

For example you develop a website. If I have the Auth2 Token of the Youtube API in the source code of the javascript file. Could someone just read the the javascript file and take the Auth2 token and use it?

Comment: Yes. You have some influence on the required skill and resources, but not much, and eventually the answer is still yes.

Comment: @GaborLengyel but isnt that bad and can be abused ?